# Short filenames in LocalServer32 entries

Tags: com, windows-installer

I have a Component in an installer Project (created with an old Installshield Version).

The Class table entry in the MSI is created correct. But when the installer runs the entry in the registry (LocalServer32) is created with a short 8.3 Name.

What can I do so that the entries in the registry are made with the full 32bit long filename?

The problem behind it:

My component tries to locate localized DLLs with the filename. But when the component is launched with the 8.3 filename the fielname returned by GetModuleFilenameis also in 8.3 format. So when it just appends DEU to the name and changes the extension to DLL to locate the localized DLLs this sometimes fails. And I can not modify this component. (I.e. CompenentName.exe tries to find CompenentNameDEU.dll)

When I register the component manually (ComponentName.exe -register) the entries are made with the full long filename and everything works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way around your problem is to use the [`GetLongPathName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980(v=vs.85).aspx) API to convert the path to the long version of the filename.

This should work regardless of whether the argument is a shortened 8.3 path or whether it's already a long path.

Comment: @xMRi, so what parts do you control then? You did call it "your component".

Comment: My component (andmy codeownership) is the main application and the installer. Another programmer owns the code of the compponent. The Problem is fixed now. The programmer now uses GetModuleFileName and after that he calls GetLongPathName on it and works with the Name he retrieves.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the rest of the registry entries that are created. I suspect you'll find something like a LocalServer32 data item (not a key) with apparent garbage in it. If so, what happens is that the 8.3 name is not used to locate the COM server. That "garbage" contains an encoding of ProductCode and Component guid that are used with MSI APIs to locate the target file, invoking repair if necessary.

So if this is what you see, the short answer is "don't use the Class table" because it creates an MSI links to find the target, not a file path.

Comment: Yes. It is as you told. But the problem is that my component returns the "Short file name" when it calls GetModuleHandle... It seams funny that when you create a process with CreateProcess and the short file name the module name is not the long fle name. I made the decision to contact the code owner of this modul to make a change.

Comment: Just to repeat myself, COM does not use that short name. It uses the encoded ProductCode and Component guid and calls MsiGetComponentPath() to locate the code file. It does not call CreateProcess() on the short file name.

Comment: It does. I can see it in the ProjectExplorer. For any reason the filename that is used is a short filename. And if you start the out of process server with a short filename GetModuleFilename returns the short filename. Or let me say: MsiGetComponentPath may return a short file name and than I get the problem.

Comment: Coincidentally, today's Old New Thing covers another aspect of this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/07/31/10546305.aspx

Comment: Funny coincidence, and yes, COM isn't the only place Darwin descriptors are used to locate the actual file. Apart from the Old New Thing shell extensions they're also in MSI shortcuts. They all decode the Darwin descriptor and call MsiGetComponentPath() or equivalent to find the actual code file to load.